# lazy load for wookmark plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, wookmark

How to add [lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to [wookmark photo plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/)?

Actually wookmark photo plugin uses auto height option. So images dimensions completely varies from one to another. When I add lazy load to the images whose height & width are not specified, the plugin loads all the images which is in out of the display area also.?

Help me adding lazy load plugin for the images whose height & width are unknown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the Wookmark plugin.  For the page that I was using it on (http://aucycling.com/gallery/), not a single image loads until all of them have loaded at which point, Wookmark will organize them.  I tried using lazy load, but that initially gives each image a fixed size.  The issue with this is that Wookmark organizes the pictures based off of the size of the placeholder image used to lazy load.

You could set a delay to the Wookmark plugin and have it kick in after the images have loaded and organize them then, but this would cause the page to restructure several times after it has appeared to be loaded.  There really isn't a good solution for this, I would recommend to just have Wookmark only load a small amount of images at a time and use its endless scroll feature.

If you really really really wanted to use lazy load, you could use php to determine the height and width of the images and set the width and height of the lazy load image to be the same as the image that is going to load.